# When would one want to use OneTuple?

Tags: haskell, tuples

I just stumbled upon the package [OneTuple](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OneTuple-0.2.1)  on hackage. I want to know it's purpose, I'm certain the author didn't create it just for the fun of it. So when can this be useful? It's quite clear what it does, but not when one would use it.

So, anyone know any cool examples when you can benefit from this? Or perhaps show the mathematical beauty behind it?

Comment: "I'm certain the author didn't create it just for the fun of it" -- you may be underestimating the Haskell community's sense of humor here.

Comment: What frog said.  See the acme package category for examples of packages with no real reason for existing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's nearly the same as the `Identity` monad, which is commonly used as the base of a monad transformer stack, except that since `OneTuple` uses `data` instead of `newtype` it has an additional bottom value.

It's interesting because it's in a sense the most trivial example of most of the type classes it implements. I don't see much of a practical use for it, though.

Comment: I only see practical use in creating an additional layer of indirection, for instance to safe the thunk inside from being evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have a (slightly silly) typeclass that operates on tuples. You have an instance for `(a,a)`, an instance for `(a,a,a)`.  You want an instance for a single value as well. But you can't just make an instance for `a` because that would overlap with everything else! You can, however, make an instance for `OneTuple a`.

Now that typeclass is a bit useless, but its easy to imagine a typeclass almost like it but more useful. In fact, this is precisely the use of `Only` in bos' mysql library: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/mysql-simple/0.2.0.2/doc/html/Database-MySQL-Simple-QueryResults.html

Answer (score 3):

This is most certainly *not* a joke, just like the identity monad implementation is not a joke.  Unlike the plain type `a` you get all the useful instances, and you get the additional bottom, which brings the singleton tuple much closer to the semantics of the other tuple types.

One use case for this is, just like the identity monad, generalization.  You have an applicative/monadic function, which has a polymorphic functor type.  For example, many useful packages like *enumerator* support operating over a user-chosen monad.  The slightly different semantics of `OneTuple` (compared to `Identity`) can be very useful, when you have complicated data dependencies or want to make use of the additional laziness, which `Identity` doesn't give you.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's something of a joke, like the [don't](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/acme-dont/1.1/doc/html/Acme-Dont.html) package. That said, `OneTuple` does add a single new value to any type (as opposed to `Maybe`, which adds two: `Nothing` and either `Just undefined` or `undefined` depending on how your boat sways). So if it ever turns out you need that, you know where to go...

Comment: `don't` seems to be quite useful for debugging purposes - for instance if you want to "comment out" some monadic operations.

Comment: I use the `--` operator for that :-)